# MongoError additional information

Tags: mongodb

I'm interested by Mongo Errors, the only useful link I found is not that useful actually.
http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/error-codes/

```
"name": "MongoError",
"err": "E11000 duplicate key error index: AyolanDB.users.$email_1  dup key: { : \"copain6@gmail.com\" }",
"code": 11000,
"n": 0,
"connectionId": 838,
"ok": 1
```

For example, what does mean the "**ok**"? That the DB is still running? What's "**n**"?

If anyone has more information about that... Because it's quite poor actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ok` - means a command successfully completed

`n` - number of document affected (insert | update | remove)

For more info, see [getLastError](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/)